# Ifelse leaving other observations as is

Tags: pandas

In R and tidy verse, there is a way to use ifelse() such that I can change several of the observations in a variable but then I can leave other observations that I don't want changed as they are but just setting else to that column (so in the example below, "Virginica and "Versicolor" would remain the same. Can't figure out how to do that in pandas.

iris = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mwaskom/seaborn-data/master/iris.csv')

Minimal reproducible example:

```
iris\
.assign(new_species = iris['species'].apply(lambda x: "set" if x=="setosa" else species))
```

This comes up with an error and if I put species in quotes, "species" becomes the actual observation.

Thanks much!

James

Comment: `iris['species'].apply(lambda x: "set" if x=="setosa" else x))` would work

Comment: Ahhh...this is what exactly what I was looking for. Thanks. I've used replace a bit, but seems like I also need to rethink in what situations to use it.

Comment: `replace` is a better fit here than ifelse, since you are *replacing*; it was a condition such as `if iris.sepal_length.lt(5) then 2 else 4`, then the ifelse logic filts in better than a replace (which wont work for this scenario anyways)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace`:

```
iris['new_spicies'] = iris['species'].replace('setosa', 'set')
```

Output:

```
     sepal_length  sepal_width  petal_length  petal_width    species new_spicies
0             5.1          3.5           1.4          0.2     setosa         set
1             4.9          3.0           1.4          0.2     setosa         set
2             4.7          3.2           1.3          0.2     setosa         set
3             4.6          3.1           1.5          0.2     setosa         set
4             5.0          3.6           1.4          0.2     setosa         set
..            ...          ...           ...          ...        ...         ...
145           6.7          3.0           5.2          2.3  virginica   virginica
146           6.3          2.5           5.0          1.9  virginica   virginica
147           6.5          3.0           5.2          2.0  virginica   virginica
148           6.2          3.4           5.4          2.3  virginica   virginica
149           5.9          3.0           5.1          1.8  virginica   virginica

[150 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a solution for the reproducible example, but if there were six values would you use replace for all of those? Maybe that is ultimately more efficient than ifelse.

Comment: replace would still work when you pass a list, e.g. `['setosa', 'some_other_thing']`

Comment: How do you mean? You would pass the list of values you want changed? Or setosa would become some_other_thing?

Comment: `replace(['thing_to_change1', 'thing_to_change2'], 'new_thing')` or `replace({'thing_to_change1': 'new_thing1', 'thing_to_change2': 'new_thing2'})`

Comment: Ah, perfect, thanks for the example!